# lightbox issue, I place the same link multiple times and the image count increases

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I have the following issue with lightbox, I want to use the same link twice in the same page:

```
<a class="lightbox cboxRelative" id="myid1" href="myimage">My Link</font></a>
<a class="lightbox cboxRelative" id="myid2" href="myimage_thesame">My Link</font></a>
```

The problem comes as both images get merged onto the lightbox instance that is initiated, therefore I see 1 of 2 images as whereas I should be seeing one image only.

What am I doing wrong in regards to lighbox implementation?

Comment: I bet you'll have more luck with this question if you post examples of the code that you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet so I'm submitting this as an answer. Hopefully we can figure this out.

I'm assuming you're using the jquery plugin from [here](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/). And I'm venturing a guess that you're javascript is using either ".lightbox" or ".cboxRelative" as a selector. If that is the case, the plugin is grabbing both links to create a lightbox. Try creating two instances of the lightbox and use the id of the link as the selector.

My suggestion may not work but if you post your javascript, I or someone else may be able to give you more specific help.